# Using a MySQL function to insert records into a table

Tags: mysql, function, sql-insert

I am trying to use a MySQL function to insert records to a permanent table. My SQL function code is similar to this:-

```
 delimiter //
    create function fn_eval 
    (
    a varchar(36),
    b int,
    c varchar(36)
    ) 
    returns bigint deterministic
begin
      declare retvalue int default 0;
      insert into eval_tbl(a,b,c,d)
      select a,b,c,d
      from
           ((select a,b,c,d from eval_tbl_1
             inner join eval_tbl_2)
             ON eval_tbl_1.c = eval_tbl_2.c)
           )

      SET retvalue=1;   
      return retvalue;
end //
delimiter ;
```

On trying to call the function:

```
select fn_eval ('1', 2, '3') from dual;
```

it returns 1. However, on trying to use this as an inline function in a query, it returns OK. I am not able to figure out the reason for this. Can someone help me on this?

Comment: How are you trying to use it?

Comment: I am trying to use it in the following format:-  select fn_eval(a,b,c),a from eval_tbl_a;

Answer (score 0):

The query that was used was correct, however, the problem was that there was a certain field which was returning duplicate values.This resulted in the query returning OK as the result. Added a few conditions to select the distinct records, after which this issue was resolved.